# ${catalina.base} in catelina.properties not replaced by CATALINA_BASE

Tags: java, tomcat

I get the exception FileNotFoundException, because ${catalina.base} has not been translated to the value of CATALINA_BASE

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${catalina.base}/conf/fourf.properties (No such file or directory)
```

I have added a property FOURF_JAVA_CONFIGURATION in catelina.properties

```
FOURF_JAVA_CONFIGURATION=${catalina.base}/conf/fourf.properties
```

When starting tomcat it logs:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat_appserver
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat_appserver
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat_appserver/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat_appserver/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

I would have expected FOURF_JAVA_CONFIGURATION to have the value /usr/share/tomcat_appserver/conf/fourf.properties. Why does that not happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by putting following line in my code:

```
configurationPath = configurationPath.replace("${catalina.base}", System.getProperty("catalina.base"));
```

I envisaged there where some automation for replacing ${catalina.base}, but obviously not